# unable to access RESTful services which build on force.com platform using Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I have create a RESTful service on Force.com using Apex below is my code.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/helloWorld/*')
global with sharing class RestWebservice {

  @HttpGet
  global static String helloWorld(){
    return 'HelloWorld';
  }

}
```

I am trying to access my RESTful services using below url:
https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/helloWorld/

In response i am geting:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date:Thu, 18 Jul 2013 07:35:44 GMT
Content-Length:96
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

[
  {
    "message": "Could not find a match for URL /helloWorld/",
    "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
]
```

Below is my class snapshot:
[image]

[image]

how can i resolve this issue ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. i can't get the hello world app to work either.

Answer (score 3):

When you putting an * (asterisk) in the end you need to write an Id or something instead of it like is described in this [document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm) .
What you are trying to accomplish i guess is more like this

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping='/helloWorld')
```

And then make this call

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer sessionId"  "https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/helloWorld"
```

Comment: I tried this iam get same error as "Could not find a match for URL /helloWorld"

Comment: Pay attention if you put a final slash after helloWorld/ . Double check spelling pay attention to characters case. Make sure the class compiled and exists in Salesforce (try access it from web interface just to make sure). Finally it should work seems you doing everything right. If still no go, please repost your new code.